# Llenar Combo en JSF y JPA

Tags: jsf, jpa

Soy nuevo utilizando JSF y JPA. Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo hacer para que en un combo que se llena de una tabla `Clientes`, aparezcan los clientes que tengo registrados y no el índice de objeto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="clienteid" value="#{historialController.selected.clienteid}" title="#{bundle.CreateHistorialTitle_clienteid}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateHistorialRequiredMessage_clienteid}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{clientesController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 2):

como te muestra el string del objeto, significa que el converter está funcionando bien, por lo tanto solo tienes que añadir la etiqueta itemLabel como te muestro a continuacion y un itemValue, que sería el valor que se guarda realmente mientras que itemLavel es solo para mostrar.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="clienteid" value="#{historialController.selected.clienteid}" title="#{bundle.CreateHistorialTitle_clienteid}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateHistorialRequiredMessage_clienteid}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{clientesController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}" 
                               itemLabel="#{cliente.nombre}"
                               itemValue="#{cliente}/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
```

La repuesta de @Alejandro Giorgi está perfecta, aunque y te sugiero si estás comenzando con JSF que aun no utilices [Omnifaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/), porque si bien es cierto que es de mucha utilidad, te abstrae de muchos conceptos de jsf que deberías conocer. Además te sugiero que incluyas [Primefaces](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/) en el proyecto, esta es digamos la biblioteca de componentes visuales más utilizada para jsf y es muy facil de incluir, además te va a suponer una buena mejora en cuanto al visual respecto a los componentes de jsf.

Comment: Olvidé poner la variable var que es quien representa a cada objeto de la lista clientesController.itemsAvailableSelectOne   <f:selectItems value="#{clientesController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}" 
                               itemLabel="#{cliente.nombre}"
                               itemValue="#{cliente} var="cliente" / >

Answer (score 1):

Lo que estás viendo en el combo es el resultado de haberse invocado el método `toString()` de tu clase Cliente. Cuando JSF recibe un request, transforma el html a un árbol de componentes. Cuando genera el rensponse, renderiza cada uno de los componentes a html. Cada vez que ocurre esto, dentro del ciclo de vida de un pedido, lo que hace JSF es convertir los datos, de como se representan de html a objetos y viceversa. En tu caso, el framework debe convertir cada elemento del combo html (texto) a tu objecto cliente (y de objeto cliente a texto cuando deba renderizar el combo). Para definir como debe hacerse esta conversión podemos implementar la interfaz [javax.faces.Converter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaus.html). La misma tiene dos métodos a implementar:

```
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        String value);
```

En este método deberías definir como se transforma a objeto (a cliente) luego de haber elegido alguna de las opciones del combo.

```
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        Object value);
```

En este otro método deberías definir que es lo que vas a mostrar como opción del combo.

Fíjate que el método `getAsObject` se invocará en el post y el método `getAsString` se invocará al generar el response.

Otra opción que tienes es usar [Omnifaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/). Tiene muchas utilidades que te salvan la vida en muchas ocasiones. Para tu caso en particular, Omnifaces te provee un [SelectItemsConverter](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter). Mirá un poco la documentación, pero verás que con este Converter especial de Omnifaces solo necesitas tener un "buen toString()" con el cual puedas identificar univocamente cada entidad (en tu caso cada cliente). Por lo que veo tu implementación del `toString` hace lo que este converter requiere y no debería ser difícil usarlo en tu proyecto.

Todo esto si tu quieres que al seleccionar una opción se guarde un objeto cliente en tu ManagedBean. Ahora, si solo quieres guardar el id del cliente seleccionado, quizás con algo como esto te alcance:

```
    <h:selectOneMenu id="clienteid" value="{#historialController.selected.clienteid}" 
        title="#{bundle.CreateHistorialTitle_clienteid}" required="true" 
        requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateHistorialRequiredMessage_clienteid}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{clientesController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}" 
        var="cliente" itemLabel="#{cliente.nombre}" itemValue="#{cliente.id}}/>
     </h:selectOneMenu>
```

En el tag `f:selectItems` puedes declarar una variable con el atributo var a la cual luego la puedes usar para definir la etiqueta: `itemLabel` y el valor que se guardará en tu ManagedBean: `itemValue`.